# Is there a pattern to avoid ever-multiplying link tables in database design?

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design

Currently scoping out a new system. Like many systems, it will be required to store documents and link them to other kinds of item. In this instance a `Document` object can belong to a `Job` or it can belong to an `Item` (which in turn belongs to a Job).

We could do this by having a JobId and an ItemId against a `Document` and leaving one or the other blank if necessary, but that's going to mean annoying conditional logic in the handling code. So, two link tables seems a better idea.

However, it is likely that we will need to link `Documents` to other items in the system at some point in the future. There are `Company` and `User` objects, for example, and we might want to record `Documents` against those. There may be more.

That would entail a proliferation of link tables which, while effective, is messy and hard to follow.

This solution is in SQL Server and will be handled in code via Entity Framework.

Are there any design principles that can allow us to hook up `Document` objects with a variety of other system objects as required in a neater and more flexible way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store two values: the id, and the type of object to which the document is attached. It doesn't allow the use of foreign keys, but is compatible with many application development frameworks.

If you have the partitioning option then you could dedicate different partitions to different object types.

You could also have multiple tables, one for job documents, one for item documents, and get an overview of all of them with a view that UNION ALL's them together. If you need uniqueness in that result set then you could use UUIDs for the primary key, or add an extra column to the view to express from which table the row was read.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. We did think of doing the id - type solution without a key but I don't *think* that's compatible with Entity Framework, which it would need to be. I left that important information out of the question - have now added it.

Comment: What brought that to mind was Rails, in which you'd create the document table with a documentable_id and documentable_type -- works well for ActiveRecord, but not very well with database foreign keys.